# Is it possible to generate strings that match a regular expression string?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

Is it possible to display the strings that match a regular expression?

Example:

Take the expression `/^AD\d{3}/`
and display `AD999`

What I'm doing is validating a string that is pretty simple either containing all numbers, a few characters maybe, and maybe a '-'. I am validating a postal code on form submit against a database of all countries that use a postal code.

I could perform it in Javascript or PHP, if that makes any difference.

Comment: In general, there are many strings which match a regex - at least, for any useful regex. What criteria do you want to use to decide which of the many matching strings should be displayed?

Comment: How would you expect to know it was AD999 and not AD001 from `/^AD\d{3}/`?

Comment: He simply wants to display an example for valid input.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the -1.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would insert 999 in place of \d{3}. Just wanting a visual for the customer to know they didn't use correct format.

Comment: And what would you insert for `\d{5,8}([c-fF-M]+.)?`? What you want to display is almost certainly dependent on a larger context than just the regex itself.

Comment: @PhilipKendall String I'm validating is pretty simple either containing all numbers, a few characters maybe, and maybe a '-'. I am just validating a postal code on form submit against a database of all countries that use a postal code.

Comment: `[^\s\S]` - that will fail :)  However, that's a good question. I'd like to have a system like that

Comment: I just decided to write a php function to reverse the expression to a string I can display for the customer to know what format is correct to catch their mistake. Easier than adding 250+ records to the database manually.

Answer (score 4):

No. That sort of feature is not available.

You can try to implement it yourself, but I don't think that's the solution for you. Simply write the messages normally. Not everything must always be dynamic.

I like your way of thinking though.

Comment: I just figured it would save having another field in the database if I could reverse it.

Comment: Why is having another field in the database a problem?

Comment: Not a problem, just a lot of work when my database I have built contains every country in the world that uses postal codes.

Comment: @Philip the more info you generate, the less you need to change should you need to refactor.

Answer (score 4):

**It is possible**.  The [developers of PEX figured it out](http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/CommentView,guid,ebbeae3f-9e53-4f67-9d30-6d8a1d2c4903.aspx).

**Don't get your hopes up**, I don't know of any javascript implementation.

Comment: Link is broken but see Pepijn answer below for a really nice JavaScript implementation

Answer (score 4):

There is one for javascript now: http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/.

Comment: This works perfectly and should be the top answer in my opinion, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I have understood your problem a little better from your additional comments.

Since your data is only postal codes, I suggest that it would possible to work in the other direction and store a *picture* in the database and automatically generate a regex from that.

For instance, UK postcodes look like `AA?99? 9AA | AA?9A 9AA` which is easily converted to a regex (using a regex!).

Comment: Or more generally, have a domain specific language from which you can generate both the example and the regex. As an aside, SAN 1TA is a valid UK postcode, used for children sending letters to Father Christmas and there are a couple of other odd examples like that. Whether you ever want to accept those on a form is a different question.

Comment: Be careful - it's `SAN TA1`. You don't want those letters going astray!